# textContent() without spaces from formatting text

Tags: javascript

I have an html like this:

```
<div id="info">
    <h1> My title </h1?
    <div>
        <p> Here is a text and one paragraph </p>
        <p> Another paragraph </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to take the inner text without the tags from the whole div#info. So I use this:

```
document.querySelector('div#info').textContent
```

And the results have some spaces like this:

```
"
    My title




Here is a text and one paragraph
Another Paragraph




"
```

Any idea if there is any command which could give the result to so one line like this:

```
 "My title Here is a text and one paragraph Another Paragraph"
```

I tries also the `innerText()` but it has again spaces.

Comment: you can use the trim() method, but to remove inner spaces is a little more difficult.

Comment: You can use regex `text.replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need a regex to remove all of the newlines and excess whitespace:

```
.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ')
```

Then you can `.trim()` the result of that call:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('div#info')
          .textContent
          .replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').trim()
)
```

```html
<div id="info">
    <h1> My title </h1>
    <div>
        <p> Here is a text and one paragraph </p>
        <p> Another paragraph </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach will have 2 spaces between `title` and `Here` as you are only replacing new line characters and OP has extra spaces in text.

Comment: @Rajesh That is not what I'm seeing in the output from `Run code snippet`

Comment: Please try using HTML instead of inline text. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1eamqd1/)

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, I've updated my answer and checked in JSFiddle - appreciate the help!

Comment: `[\n\r]` is also `\s`, so the pipe is redundant. A simple `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` should suffice.

Answer (score 7):

Since you have multiple spaces in your text, you can use `string.replace` to replace multiple spaces by single space.

You should also use `string.trim()` to exclude trailing and leading spaces.

```js
var text = document.querySelector('div#info').textContent
console.log(text.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim())
```

```html
<div id="info">
    <h1> My title </h1>
    <div>
        <p> Here is a text and one paragraph </p>
        <p> Another paragraph </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex to remove all spaces.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div#info').textContent.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' '));
```

```html
<div id="info">
    <h1> My title </h1?
    <div>
        <p> Here is a text and one paragraph </p>
        <p> Another paragraph </p>
    </div>
</div>
```